# how to Display error message in console mode in VC++?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, mfc, command

I am working on a VC++ windows application which support GUI as well as non-GUI based execution. The non GUI based execution is designed for console mode purpose. Now, if I executed that application in GUI mode I can show message box for user acknowledgement in case of error or exception.

But in Console mode, I have to execute like

c:> myapp.exe -options -MS Yes

If user type the above command without "-options"keyword. I want to display a error message in console mode.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to check that the `options` key is entered and exit if not. The approximate code of this solution:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if (...) // Check for options presence here
    {
        cerr << "Myapp should be run as myapp.exe -options -MS Yes" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    ... // Some actual work here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for acting on my questions.
i followed your answer. cerr is not printing msg in console. 

if(/*no options found case*/) { cerr << "err msg" <<endl; }

Comment: @saran Then you may use `cout`

Comment: `cerr` is not redirected to standard out by default, on Windows.

Comment: I tried cerr and cout both. could not print err msg in console.